# How to migrate mining pool data to another server?

Tags: monerod, mining-pools

I have mined for a pool and would like to transfer my data to another pool. How can that be done?

Comment: There is very little info here for us to go on. Please do some research and come back and phrase your question more clearly.

Comment: Do you own a pool or use a pool?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand, you want to move the "work" you've done on a pool that hasn't paid out -- to another pool?

That can't be done. At best you'd have to contact the pool admin and ask that they deposit the pending XMR to your wallet. Chances are of it hasn't paid out, you've not met the minimum requirement and there would be additional fees for a non-standard payout. There should be a FAQ or help section on your pools website.

Comment: thanks  I know There is a problem, I burst into the block before and after the blasting block burst just 1 hours, XMR paid to my wallet, the miner's payment is 0 to wait for payment is also what reason